# when creating a new file, vscode let me select an editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

When creating a new file, vscode let me select an editor. It hasn't do so, and I don't want to choose one, because I only use the Built-in editor.
[image: this is my screenshot]

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? You may give more info about what you aim to achieve and which problems you are encountering. Check here for how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Everytime, I click "file"-->"new file". Vscode let me select an editor.I only have one selection, "Built-in".

Comment: My version is 2020 (version 1.47) for Mac.

Comment: That's a bug in the new release. Corresponding issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102289

Comment: Does anybody know of a way to force plain text files without extension?

Comment: @Alex please consider making your comment THE answer.