# How to disable "Select Editor for Untitled-1"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

- When ever I open a new file in VS Code getting the following option
- Tried reinstallation / cleared all the settings, but still this continues

[image]

Comment: search the question history a few days and you find the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62949224/9938317 Using images makes it hard to search the text.

Comment: @Mark I am already using 1.47.2 - looks like that the build has this bug, Down graded to 1.46.1 and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

- Thanks to @rioV8
- Downgraded to 1.46.1 version and it works fine
- Got the older version here for [Mac](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.46.1/darwin/stable)

**Update:** 14-Aug-2020

This issue is addressed in Version: 1.48.0

```
Version: 1.48.0
Commit: db40434f562994116e5b21c24015a2e40b2504e6
Date: 2020-08-13T08:03:27.059Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
```